# AJAX get for this weeks birthdays

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter, date-time, ajax

Greetings fellow sharepoint warriors.

I am trying to understand the way all the filtering goes and I've stumbled upon a problem.

I would like to get items from list where birthday falls in current week.
I am using Monday-Sunday if this is any help.

I have a column, which is Date & Time.

```
$.ajax({
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api" + "/web/lists/getbytitle('Workers')/Items?$select=FirstName,Birthday,LastName", //THE ENDPOINT
   method: "GET",
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
   success: function (data) {
         //DO SOMETHING WITH DATA
   }
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to filter date exactly. I know that filtering in range is done as following

```
$filter=(StartDate ge datetime'2014-01-01T00%3a00%3a00') and (EndDate le datetime'2014-04-30T00%3a00%3a00'
```

But how would i use a column information in that specific filter? If that was possible i could calculate day and month seperately and use jquery current year to filter between this weeks birthdays.

EDIT:/ Tried this out

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workers')/Items?$select=FirstName,Birthday,LastName&$filter=(Birthday ge datetime'1980-01-01T00%3a00%3a00') and (Birthday le datetime'2014-01-01T23%3a59%3a59') and (Day eq '21')
```

This gives me error:
The field 'Day' of type 'Calculated' cannot be used in the query filter expression.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd suggest using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) and calculating the exact date that you need for each, then query rest based on that.

somethings like

```
var monday = moment().startOf('week').add(1, 'days'); //beginning of Monday midnight

var sunday = moment().startOf('week').add(7, 'days').add(23, "hours"); //end of Sunday 11:00PM
```

Then use

```
"_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workers')/Items?$select=FirstName,Birthday,LastName&$filter=(Birthday ge " + monday + ") and (Birthday le " + sunday + ")
```

Comment: But the fact that birthday is f.e.  7th semptember of 1980 won't be problem here?
Or does this accept every year now?

Comment: ah, you may want to use that date and then something like monday.month(), monday.day() and moment().year() to ignore the year value.

Comment: nvm, i used sharepoint 2010 endpoint and used odate month and day function combined with momentjs values and now it is working like a charm! Thanks!